# Unit cinder-api.service could not be found - Openstack

Tags: openstack

I installed openstack devstack on ubuntu 18.04

when I login to horizon. it logs in.

when I try to check status of all services. Services are not found.

So when I execute `service cinder-api status` it gives me  `Unit cinder-api.service could not be found.` (Same for all services. Installation was successful. although it was interrupted due to network. But is that issue with this (But horizon dashboard opens))

What is wrong with this. As because of this I am not able to create volumes (I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason for the message**:

The services of the projects are down. For example - n-api, c-api, c-sch..... To rectify it, manually trigger the services using command prompt **or** Run `unstack.sh` and again `clean.sh` and then `stack.sh`, this will create a new openstack.

**Note**: While using devstack one important thing need to be taken care is "***Never shutdown the machine. If it is shutdown all the services goes down.***"

Comment: Yeah. I did this. And got solved. But u should get the reward. :) Was about to answer own question. ;)

Comment: Oh. About. Note. It is made for development purpose. Isnt this bad then? To keep machine On? Can I hibernate? I have booted this from USB.